# Salesforce REST API and Javascript Integration

Tags: rest-api

I am following [this guide](https://iwritecrappycode.wordpress.com/2012/10/31/access-salesforce-rest-api-with-javascript/) to invoke a REST API on salesforce server side and get a JSON response.

1. I created a salesforce site, and added the VF page
2. Ensured that the page and classes have access.

When I am invoking the URL as mentioned down below for query I am getting the following response.

```
{
    "success": false,
    "sObjects": [],
    "requestURI": "/kvh/respondentPortal/get/",
    "params": ["kvh", "respondentPortal", "get", " "],
    "message": "No auth token provided. Please provide one with ?authToken= in the request url"
}
```

I have kvh since it is a namespaced org.

Answer (score 4):

The error seems fairly clear. You need to be having a parameter called 'authToken' in your GET request.

Your code is failing here

```
 if(RestContext.request.params.get('authToken') == null)
            {
                throw new applicationException('No auth token provided. Please provide one with ?authToken= in the request url');
            }
```

Check the syntax of your GET URL to see that the `authToken` is being properly populated. This should fix it.

E.g.

`<URL>?param1=value1&authToken='value'&paramx=valuex` and so on and so forth